# ObservedObject change doesn't redraw SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I try to build rather complicated View in SwiftUI. Structure is like this:

```
struct ContentView<V: SpaceVertexProtocol>: View  where V.Coord.Axis : StyledAxisProtocol{
    
    @EnvironmentObject var environment: ViewsEnvironments<V>
    @ObservedObject var global: GlobalEnvironment<V>
    
    var body: some View {
        // It will be HStack, for a while just one view
        SpaceVerticesView(coordinates: $global.coordinates, vertices: $global.vertices)    
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5))
                .environmentObject(environment.spaceVerticesView)
    }
}

public struct SpaceVerticesView<V:SpaceVertexProtocol> : View {
    ...
    @Binding var coordinates : [V.Coord]
    ...
    func updateCoordnates { 
       coordinates = ... // yes, this updates view, they're changed by `coordinates[index].at = something`
    }
    public var body: some View {
        ...
        SpotsView(coordinates: $coordinates,....)
        ...
    }

struct SpotsView<V:SpaceVertexProtocol> : View {
    ...
    @Binding var coordinates: [V.Coord]
    var spots: [SpotView<V>] {
         var result: [SpotView<V>] = []
         ...
         //counts and adds views initiated as:
            result.append(SpotView(coordinates: $coordinates,...)
         ... 
        return result
    }

    var body: some View {
        return ZStack {
            // makes some SpotView on top
            ForEach(0..<spots.count, id: \.self) { index in
                return self.spots[index]
            }
        }
    }
```

and two levels more, always `coordinates` are passed as `$coordinates` to `@Binding` variable.
In the deepest view, var `body` returns `Shape`

```
    var body {
       ...
       return spotShape
        .contentShape(spotShape.clickArea).offset(x: 0, y: shift)
        .onTapGesture {
            print ("Tap gesture:",self)
            print (self.coordinates, targetCoordinates)
            self.coordinates = targetCoordinates
```

I can see `coordinates` are updated, but view isn't redrawn.
If I click outside of `clickArea` , `SpaceVerticesView.updateCoordinates(...)` is fired, `coordinates` are changed and View is redrawn. Is `Shape` `@Binding` invalid? Why no reaction?

When `coordinates` was part of `@EnvironmentObject` it was OK.

Comment: By my experience Binding often does not work properly on deep hierarchies. It is most appropriate between two views. For deeper it is more reliable to use explicit own view model ObservedObject/ObservableObject pattern.

Comment: Can you link me some example, please? I’m still learning and my brain is almost exploding.